# Using constinit variable to initialize a constexpr variable

Tags: c++, c++20

Look at this little example:

```
constinit int a = 0;
constexpr int b = a;
```

clang doesn't compile it ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/pnsmQS)):

> 2:15: error: constexpr variable 'b' must be initialized by a constant expression

Is this correct diagnostics?

If yes, why doesn't the standard allow this? I understand, that `a`'s value may change during running (or even during dynamic-initialization), but at constant-initialization, its value is known, so it could be used to initialize `b`.

Comment: If you allow that, do you also allow [this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9Eycze)? Would that astonish readers?

Comment: @chris: yeah, that's a good one. But a different one, as in my example, `b` is global. We already have differing rules for globals, so maybe the standard could allow this, if `b` is global.

Comment: My comment on that is that every special case in the language comes with its own complexity. Perhaps this case was considered and there wasn't enough motivation to support it, or perhaps it wasn't considered at all. That said, it would be interesting to see a summary of such an in-meeting discussion.

Comment: It is the same as `void foo(){ int a = 0; constexpr int b = a; }`, `a` is not a constant expression.

Comment: So you want to `a` to be treated as a constant expression depending on how it is initialized and on the context it is being used in? C++ already suffers a lot from context-sensitivity.

Comment: @geza you are aware that changing to `constinit const` *fixes* your example ?

Comment: @darune: yes. But I want `a` to be non-const, that's the whole point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the diagnostic is correct. `constexpr` variables must be initialized with a constant expression, and `a` is not a constant expression (it's a mutable variable).

The purpose of `constinit` ([P1143](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1143r2.html)) is to force a variable declaration to be ill-formed if it's *initialization* is not constant. It doesn't change anything about the variable itself, like it's type or anything (in the way that `constexpr` is implicitly `const`). Silly example:

```
struct T {
    int i;
    constexpr T(int i) : i(i) { }
    T(char c) : i(c) { }
};

constinit T c(42); // ok
constinit T d('X'); // ill-formed
```

That is all `constinit` is for, and the only real rule is [[dcl.constinit]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constinit#2):

> If a variable declared with the `constinit` specifier has dynamic initialization ([basic.start.dynamic]), the program is ill-formed.
>   [ *Note*: The `constinit` specifier ensures that the variable is initialized during static initialization ([basic.start.static]).
>   — *end note*
>    ]

The const in `constinit` refers only to the initialization, not the variable, not any types. Note that it also doesn't *change* the kind of initialization performed, it merely diagnoses if the wrong kind is performed.

In:

```
constinit int a = 0;
constexpr int b = a;
```

`0` is a constant expression, so the initialization of `a` is well-formed. Once we get past that, the specifier doesn't do anything. It's equivalent to:

```
int a = 0; // same behavior, a undergoes constant initialization
constexpr int b = a;
```

Which is straightforwardly ill-formed.

---

> but at constant-initialization, its value is known, so it could be used to initialize `b`.

Sure, at this moment. What about:

```
constinit int a = 0;
cin >> a;
constexpr int b = a;
```

That's obviously  not going to fly. Allowing this would require extending what a constant expression is (already the most complex rule in the standard, in my opinion) to allow for non-constant variables but only immediately after initialization? The complexity doesn't seem worth it, since you can always write:

```
constexpr int initializer = 0;
constinit int a = initializer;
constexpr int b = initializer;
```

Comment: This is not entirely true - `constinit const` can be used in a constexpr - and it's supposed to be the same as constexpr.

Comment: @darune What is not entirely true? Yes, because `const int`, if constant initialized, can be used as a constant expression. That has nothing to do with `constinit`.

Comment: "would require extending what a constant expression is". As I see, yes. It would be just another bullet point: "during static-initialization, `constinit` equals to `constexpr`". But I agree, it doesn't worth it. Thanks for suggesting a reasonable workaround.

Comment: @geza That bullet point wouldn't work at all. The `cin >> a` could appear in a static initialization context. It just asks leads to more questions.

Comment: @Barry: how? Doesn't `cin >> a` require dynamic initialization context?

Comment: @geza Yeah, you're right. You would merely have to ignore intervening modifications, which wouldn't at all be confusing.

Comment: @Barry So why the standard prevent from using `constexpr` and `constinit` at the same time? It seems they do not conflict with each other.

Comment: @KaiGu `constexpr` implies `constinit`, why would you even want to write both?

Answer (score 2):

`constexpr` combines `constinit` and `const` without exception.

`constinit` forces initialization with a compiletime constant expression, and during static initialization, disallowing dynamic initialization. It does not change the variable itself in any way though.

`const` forbids changing the variable, though can be weakened by `mutable` members.

Both *together* make it a compiletime constant expression.

In summary, yes, the diagnostic is right.

Answer (score 1):

**is this correct diagnostics?**

I would say yes. According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constinit):

> constinit - specifies that a variable must have static initialization,
>   i.e. zero initialization and constant initialization, otherwise the
>   program is ill-formed.

Static (constant) initialization and constant expression are different concepts in that a constant expression may be used in a constant initialization *but not the other way around*. `constinit` shouldn't be confused with *const*. It means the initialization (only) is constant.

However, `constinit const` can be used in a `constexpr` and they are supposed to be the same.

**Counter-example:**

```
constinit int a = 0;

struct X{
    X() {
        a = 4;
    }
};

X x{};

constexpr int b = a;
```

What is `b` supposed to be ?
The point is that `a` can be changed in non-const ways before `b` is *seen*.

Comment: ... as it is no form of `const` at all.

Comment: @Deduplicator: right. But it just needs one little sentence: "during static initialization, `constinit` variables are handled as if they were `constexpr`".